# Is there a command to see if there was a thermal cut off in my laptop?

Tags: shutdown, debian

Scenario:

The computer shuts off randomly. Sometimes, it shuts off by, first the monitor goes off, and some seconds later the whole computer turns off.

The current "sensors" reading is:

```
$sensors

acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +64.0°C  (crit = +100.0°C)
temp2:        +64.0°C  (crit = +100.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +64.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +56.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +64.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

radeon-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +63.0°C
```

I would like to know if there is a way/command as above to see if thermal shutdown occured / cut off and if so when. Or in the BIOS?

Specs: Debian 8. Ram 4GB. HDD 500GB. Dell N4110 series.

Answer (score 0):

In some bios is the option of what to do in case of overheat. You can check your bios settings. 
Warning, if is really a temperature problem, and you desactivate the control you can damage the cpu.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple script which logs temperature every couple of seconds:

```
while true; do
  date >> ~/t_log.txt
  sensors >> ~/t_log.txt
  sleep 10
done
```

Keep the script running and wait for your system to shutdown. Then reboot and check if the temperature recorded in the log got near the limit.